# Show that a function $f$ is concave at a certain interval

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization

Given a function $$f(x) = -x^4 + 40x^3 - 400x^2 + 1000x$$
subject to the following constraints:

$$x^2 + x \leq 500,\quad x \geq 0$$

Prove that it is concave on the following interval $[0,4]$.

I don't know how to prove concavity on an interval.

Could I prove that $f''(0) = 0$ and that $f''(4) = 0$ which tells me that they are critical points (aka points where concavity/convexity changes) and then grab a random number in between them and prove for example that $f(1)$ is concave cause $f''(1) \leq 0$?

Comment: $f'(0)=1000$. So your approach is wrong. Calculate $f''(x)$ and check where it changes sign.

Comment: Find the range of values of $x$ for which $f''(x) < 0$, because $f''(x) < 0 \implies$ concavity